# GTM - is it possible to disregard an event click on a trigger if element clicked twice and limit amount of clicks on an element

Tags: google-tag-manager

A scenario has risen where I am trying to track button clicks. (There are several on the page as they are toggable filters).

Each button has a class relevant to it IE .filter .Dogs , .filter .Cats

When someone toggles a filter, the button's parent element gains the class "selected". I tried to track this, using the match css selector option of .selected>.filter

Unfortunately GTM doesnt seem to detect the "selected" class appearing, so I thought would it be possible to disregard the event click if the element was clicked twice and also limit the amount that the element could be clicked.

Thank you

Comment: what are you using for tracking? GA? Adobe? Piwik?

Comment: Hi Matus, Im using GA.

Comment: Can you please provide the example of you html and how you tried to configure GTM

Comment: Use dataLayer implementations and track for custom events. Finally, you can use trigger configurations inside specific tags if you want to only let the tag fire ones per page for example.

Comment: Hi Marco,

Thats excellent thank you! Just what I was looking for.